# Force CKEditor image2 plugin to set width and heigth inside the syle

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor 4.4, and I tried to use ACF to force the [image2](http://ckeditor.com/addon/image2) plugin to set `width` and `height` as CSS properties (in the `style` attribute), instead to use the corresponding `<img>` tag attributes.

In other terms, what I get now using the `editor.getData()` method is something like that:

```
<img src="text.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
```

but I want this other form:

```
<img src="text.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px" />
```

I tried to reach this result using `allowedContent` and `disallowedContent` in the `config.js` file. This is what I tried (see [this](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_disallowed_content-section-how-to-allow-everything-except...) for references):

```
//Allow everything
config.allowedContent = {
    $1: {
        // Use the ability to specify elements as an object.
        elements: CKEDITOR.dtd,
        attributes: true,
        styles: true,
        classes: true
    }
};

config.disallowedContent = "img[width,height]";
```

With this, the result is simply that `width` and `height` are no more set (neither as attributes nor in the style), the image cannot be resized and the Image Properties dialog no longer include the input boxes related to image size.

I also tried to reverse the solution propesed by [Marco Cortellino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/760819/marco-cortellino) in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051896/ckeditor-prevent-adding-image-dimensions-as-a-css-style/6056896#6056896), without positive results.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why do you want to set them as styles? There were complains for years that the old image plugin uses styles and people were totally right, because attributes used with proper styling through stylesheets have more power and are just correct. So what's your case?

Comment: It's a bit complicated to explain in so few words... I need them as style because I use it in other contexts, in which data from the editor is used in other HTML pages, with external stylesheet that must not overwrite image size. I could process data to transform attributes to style, but I don't know how...

Comment: You can override image2's [`upcast`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.definition-property-upcast) and [`downcast`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.definition-property-downcast) methods. Image2 needs attributes internally, but these methods control data. You can override them on the [`widgetDefinition`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-widgetDefinition) event. I don't have enough time to show entire solution, but you should be able to figure out how to do that by looking into the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by override the `downcast` and `upcast` methods of image2 plugin (as [Reinmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1464696/reinmar) has suggested).

This method processes the image element before it is processed when the `editor.getData()` method is called.

Therefore, the following code represents a possible solution:

```
CKEDITOR.on("instanceCreated", function (ev) {
    ev.editor.on("widgetDefinition", function (evt) {
        var widgetData = evt.data;

        if (widgetData.name != "image" || widgetData.dialog != "image2") return;

        //Override of upcast
        if (!widgetData.stdUpcast) {
            widgetData.stdUpcast = widgetData.upcast;

            widgetData.upcast = function (el, data) {
                var el = widgetData.stdUpcast(el, data);

                if (!el) return el;

                var attrsHolder = el.name == 'a' ? el.getFirst() : el;
                var attrs = attrsHolder.attributes;

                if (el && el.name == "img") {
                    if (el.styles) {
                        attrs.width = (el.styles.width + "").replace('px', '');
                        attrs.height = (el.styles.height + "").replace('px', '');

                        delete el.styles.width;
                        delete el.styles.height;

                        attrs.style = CKEDITOR.tools.writeCssText(el.styles);
                    }                      
                }

                return el;
            }
        }

        //Override of downcast
        if (!widgetData.stdDowncast) {
            widgetData.stdDowncast = widgetData.downcast;

            widgetData.downcast = function (el) {

                el = this.stdDowncast(el);

                var attrsHolder = el.name == 'a' ? el.getFirst() : el;
                var attrs = attrsHolder.attributes;

                var realWidth, realHeight;

                var widgets = ev.editor.widgets.instances;
                for (widget in widgets) {

                    if (widgets[widget].name != "image" || widgets[widget].dialog != "image2") {
                        continue;
                    }

                    realWidth = $(widgets[widget].element.$).width();
                    realHeight = $(widgets[widget].element.$).height();
                }

                var style = CKEDITOR.tools.parseCssText(attrs.style)

                if (attrs.width) {
                    style.width = realWidth + "px";
                    delete attrs.width;
                }
                if (attrs.height) {
                    style.height = realHeight + "px";
                    delete attrs.height;
                }

                attrs.style = CKEDITOR.tools.writeCssText(style);

                return el;
            }
        }
    });
});
```