# Remove image height and width in CKeditor's image dialog

Tags: ckeditor

Since my website is using a new frontend framework, all the images are default max-width:100%; This works great since the content container force images to be the correct size.
But the (awesome) Ckeditor in the background sets the image width and height when I insert an image. All the CMS users have to manualy clear this fields all the time. It's a little thing, but it start to be annoying.

I tried to reset the image height and width when inserting a value with the "setValue" function, but still the height and width gets filled in automatically.

```js
element = dialog.getContentElement( 'info', 'txtWidth' ); if(element) element.setValue('');
```

It works, but get overwritten directly.

I scan through the sourcecode but it seems to be there is no option to avoid filling in the dimensions.

Do I have to rewrite the sourcecode (don't like this because of updates etc.) or does anybody know a better solution?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051896/ckeditor-prevent-adding-image-dimensions-as-a-css-style

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, I read that one but thought my question was different. Due the answer of AlfonsoML I now see this is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you adjust the CKEditor settings so it uses attributes instead of inline styles for the images you won't have this problem, the image will show correctly all the time.

Comment: I see, because CSS will overrule attributes. Wow, that was simple. Thanks a lot!