# How to prevent CKEditor from adding inline height, width styles to img tags?

Tags: ckeditor

I have the following in my configuration:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
config.disallowedContent = 'img {width,height}';
```

Still, when adding an image, saving the form, and looking at the resulting HTML, I see:

```
<img src="/uploads/ckeditor/pictures/759/image.jpg" style="width: 227px; height: 300px;">
```

Based on all the docs I've read, [and answers I've seen on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051896/ckeditor-prevent-adding-image-dimensions-as-a-css-style), those two config lines should take care of it, but they don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [Disallowed Content documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_disallowed_content) explains:

> It is not possible to disallow content when the Advanced Content Filter is disabled by setting `CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent` to `true`.

If you want to proceed in this way ("allow everything, except inline width and height styles on images") check the [How to Allow Everything Except...](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_disallowed_content-section-how-to-allow-everything-except...) section.

However, a much better solution would be to just extend the [automatic mode](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter-section-automatic-mode) and disallow what you need as described in the [Automatic mode but disallow certain tags/properties](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf-section-automatic-mode-but-disallow-certain-tags%2Fproperties) scenario.

Comment: Well, I read through those docs, but didn't realize that the `allowedContent = true` line would have to be removed before the `disallowedContent` statement would work as I wanted.